# Have a website using version 4.9.11 and the Appearance option does not appear on Dashboard

Tags: editor

We have a very old version of Wordpress and several editing options do not appear on the Dashboard including Appearance and Plugins.  It's possible that the original creator of the website disabled these options somehow.  We are now stuck and cannot edit the look of our website theme.  Need advice please!

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to one of the Twenty-X themes. If the option is showing up again, enable the plugins and the theme step by step until it goes away again. This will tell you where to look. And welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! :)

Comment: Have you double-checked whether your user is an Administrator? Perhaps you only have a lesser role, which doesn't have access to theme options? You could also double-check what capabilities the Administrator role has in the database and add back the standard ones.